Beginner Weather API issues
Can anyone tell me where I went wrong in this code? It triggers once, and always displays the same town name.
const Weather = () => {

    const [zipCode, setZipCode] = useState("");
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);


    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=36578,us&units=imperial&appid=da2f2d11af56e955015eed08e226b806";

    const apiKey = "...";


    const getWeatherData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(url, {
              
            });
            setWeather(response.data)
            setError(null)
            console.log(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            setError("Error while fetching weather details")
        }

    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setZipCode(e.target.value)
    };

    const handleClick = () => {
        getWeatherData();
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="weather-container">
                <h1 className="weather-header">Weather App</h1>
                <div className="weather-form">
                    <input
                        placeholder="Enter Zip"
                        name={zipCode}
                        onChange={(e) => { handleChange(e) }}
                        value={zipCode}
                    />
                    <button onClick={() => { handleClick() }}> Get Weather </button>
                </div>

                {error !=null && (<p className="error-message">{error}</p>)}
                {
                    weather != null && (
                        <div className="weather-info">
                            <h2>Name : {weather.name}</h2>
                            <p>Temperature : {weather.main.temp}°F</p>
                            <p>Description : {weather.weather[0].description}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                }

            </div>
        </>
    );
};
export default Weather

I have tried changing the input values to display differently. I am unsure why it does not update.

You're calling .get() with an empty options object? You're not actually using zipCode.

Is that your actual API key? If so... you leaked your key here and need to regenerate it.

How do you mean on the zipCode not being used? how should it be used?

You need to pass it as param to your get request - notice how you set the zip code but never read it or involve it as part of your request. You currently just have a zip hard coded in your URL.

rip ye it was, good thing I made a second.

You have a couple of issues:
Your url variable has the zip code 36578 hard coded. an easy fix for this would be to declare your url variable within your getWeatherData function:
const getWeatherData = async () => {        
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zipCode},us&units=imperial&appid=da2f2d11af56e955015eed08e226b806`
    try {
            const response = await axios.get(url, {
              
            });
            setWeather(response.data)
            setError(null)
            console.log(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            setError("Error while fetching weather details")
        }
    
    }


Also, you exposed your api key, you will want to regenerate it so everyone on the internet doesn't use it!
